# Unexpected behaviour from sorting functions

Tags: c, sorting, segmentation-fault, qsort

As a homework, I've written this program that is supposed to sort a console input using qsort_r (this is the one thing I can't change, we're required to use qsort_r). We were supposed to implement three different sorting functions; compVal sorts the inputs normally by value, compOnes orders the inputs by the amount of 1s their bit value contains, and compBitSeq orders them by the longest bit sequence (and the sorting is supposed to work both ways, hence the direction variable).

The normal sorting function works fine. I can't get compOnes and compBitSeq to work, though. I've tried out the auxiliary functions countOnes and bitSequence on their own; they seem to work just fine and do what I expect them to. The program as a whole, however, gives me a segmentation error when I try to tun it.

Since I'm not super secure with pointers yet, I cannot really pinpoint what is wrong here. I do assume that there might be a problem in passing a function to a function and that I'm not passing all the values correctly, but I'm not sure how else to do this? I have tried putting everything in one function, which is very unelegant since I have to do the same loop to find both acount and bcount, but that also didn't work. qsort_r is also cutting down my flexibility here since I have to stick to the data types that the function requires.

---

I've now got rid of the segmentation fault, interchanging the function strcomp with memcmp did the trick! Now I do get an output, but it's not as desired and I can't get behind what's wrong here. I've tried out my countOnes and bitSeq functions with a couple of values and the output tells me that the values that are being determined are right (I commented that in my code so I know what order it should be in). But the sorting seems to be totally random (well it probably isn't, but I really can't tell what it sorts by... and I do feel like the output is different every time, even with the same numbers, especially if I enter them in a different order), even for the totally normal sorting sequence.

If this helps, I now modified my functions so the print what numbers they are comparing, and... it's some negative numbers:
number a: -41, number b: -39, order: -2
number a: -34, number b: -31, order: -3
number a: -36, number b: -34, order: -2
number a: -41, number b: -36, order: -5
number a: -39, number b: -36, order: -3
3, 15, 7, 97, 32

(obviously, the numbers came out as they went in, since the values all give a negative result...)

Where do they come from? Apparently I passed something wrong but I can't tell what...? Maybe some of the data types got jumbled up, but I can't find out which and where. I tried to change around some things, but that didn't help.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compVal (const void *a, const void *b, void *direction) {
    int order = memcmp(a, b, sizeof(char)) * *(int *) direction;
    printf("number a: %d, number b: %d, order: %d\n", *(char *)a, *(char *)b, order);
    if (order > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (order < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int countOnes (char number) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (8 * sizeof(char)); i++) {
        if (number & 1) {
            counter += 1;
        }
        number = number >> 1;
    }
    return counter;
}

int bitSequence (char number) {
    int bit = number & 1;
    number = number >> 1;
    int current = 1, max = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < (8 * sizeof(char)); i++) {
        if ((number & 1) == bit) {
            current += 1;
            if (current > max) {
                max = current;
            }
        } else {
            current = 1;
        }
        bit = number & 1;
        number = number >> 1;
    }
    return max;
}

int compOnes (const void *a, const void *b, void *direction) {
    char achar = *(char *) a, bchar = *(char *) b;
    char acount = countOnes(achar);
    char bcount = countOnes(bchar);
    //return memcmp(&acount, &bcount, sizeof(char)) * *(int *) direction;
    printf("ones a: %d, ones b: %d\n", acount, bcount);
    return compVal(&acount, &bcount, &direction);
}

int compBitSeq (const void *a, const void *b, void *direction) {
    char achar = *(char *) a, bchar = *(char *) b;
    char aseq =  bitSequence(achar);
    char bseq = bitSequence(bchar);
    //return memcmp(&aseq, &bseq, sizeof(char)) * *(int *) direction;
    printf("sequence a: %d, sequence b: %d\n", aseq, bseq);
    return compVal(&aseq, &bseq, &direction);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("At least 2 values needed for sorting\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int direction = 1;

    qsort_r(&argv[1], argc - 1, sizeof(char *), compVal, &direction);           // 3, 7, 15, 32, 97

    //qsort_r(&argv[1], argc - 1, sizeof(char *), compOnes, &direction);        // 32, 3, (7, 97), 15

    //qsort_r(&argv[1], argc - 1, sizeof(char *), compBitSeq, &direction);      // (97, 15), (7, 32), 3

    //char test1 = countOnes(3), test2 = countOnes(7), test3 = countOnes(15), test4 = countOnes(32), test5 = countOnes(97);
    //printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);    // 2, 3, 4, 1, 3

    //test1 = bitSequence(3), test2 = bitSequence(7), test3 = bitSequence(15), test4 = bitSequence(32), test5 = bitSequence(97);
    //printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);    // 6, 5, 4, 5, 4

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (i == argc -1) {
            printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%s, ", argv[i]);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: `argv` is array of `char*`, not `int*`. this(`*(int *) a`) has  alignment problems.

Comment: Does the return value produced by the comparing function have to be -1, 0 or 1 for correct results? Or can it just be ANY positive or negative value? Not sure if i have to consider anything else here...

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the sort function.

Comment: Ok no, that's not it either, apparently the numbers that I'm comparing are already wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a pointer to `int` to `strcmp()`, that invokes *undefined behavior* because `strcmp()` expects a `nul` terminated sequence of bytes which an integer is not.

Try with

```
memcmp(a, b, sizeof(int));
```

Also `sizeof(char)` is always 1, whereas `CHAR_BIT` is not necessarily `8` so this

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8 * sizeof(char); i++)
```

can be

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < CHAR_BIT ; i++)
```

instead.

Comment: ha. that did get rid of the segmentation fault, thank you! however i just realized that the functions are NOT doing what I wanted them too, after all. but that's a different story...